# PHP: Subtract minutes from ISO 8601 format

Tags: php, time, shopify, iso

I want to subtract 5 minutes from ISO 8601 time that I got using $formatedDate = date("c");

I want to use the time like this: 'created_at_min' => $formatedDate,

So I would need to subtract the 5 minutes.

How can I do this? I know that for regular time formats we can use strtotime.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
$formatedDate = date("c");

$formatedDate = date("c", strtotime("-5 minutes", strtotime($formatedDate)));
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. However, I tried using it I get an error: "Notice: Undefined variable: formatedDate in file.php on line 15" which is the line that you posted.